# Swift: didSelectItemAtIndexpath function not work of json

Tags: ios, json, swift, tableview, collectionview

i have three Controller. in first CategoryCollectionViewController, next listTableViewController and  finally has DescriptionCollectionViewController. in Controllers passed json data perfectly. but i got no idea what code i should write in `didSelectRowAt_indexPath` function of ListTableViewController.

**The first CategoryCollectionViewController**

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let controller1 = ListTableView()
    controller1.product_id = arrCategory[indexPath.item].id!
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller1, animated: true)
}
```

** CategoryCollectionViewController Json web file**
[image]

**The second ListTableViewController**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
```

`tell me please what code i have to write here for push ViewController`

```
}
```

**ListTableController and DescriptionCollectionViewController's json web file is same**

just different is `product_image` value have to load in ListTableViewController's cell and `all_images` value have to load in DescriptionCollectionViewController's cell.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve on `didSelectRow`? Please format your question and ask specific problem. The question, in it's current state, is very broad and unlikely to receive any relevant answers

Comment: @Malik want to `push ViewController`

Answer (score 2):

You have to write this code for pushing view-controller after setting the [Storyboard Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478411/how-do-i-give-an-identifier-to-a-view-controller-within-my-storyboard):

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let controller1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"ListTableView") as! ListTableView
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller1, animated: true)
}
```

I am assuming that the StoryBoard Id will be same as your controller class name so you can set StoryBoard Id in StoryBoard -> identity inspector.

**NOTE:- Replace the identifier in case of push another view controller Just like that:**

```
let controller1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"DescriptionCollectionViewController") as! DescriptionCollectionViewController
```

Comment: i am coding programmatically. next i want to push from ListTableController to DescriptionCollectionViewController. in there your code is not working.

Comment: Okay, whats error you are facing? Also, you can replace the name of view-controller.

Comment: after write this code  `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let controller1 = DescriptionCollectionView(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        controller1.product_id = arrProduct[indexPath.item].id!
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller1, animated: true)
    }`  i got message `DescriptionViewController `Value of type 'DescriptionCollectionView' has no member 'product_id'`

Comment: i am working without storyboard, it is programmatically everything.

Comment: Basically, you have to set the storyboard-id in order to access the view-controller..

Comment: i have three controller Everything i did programmatically, i have success to perform pushViewController from CategoryCollectionViewController to ListTableViewController. but got the problem when i went to push from ListTableViewController to DescriptionCollectionViewController.

Comment: What problem you got?

Comment: Brother! please come to this link to help me. I made multiple UIButton in a indexPath in a UICollectionViewCell programmatically.  the UIButton does view everything except addTarget function not click..... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169737/swift-multiple-uibutton-in-a-indexpath-in-a-uicollectionviewcell-programmatical

Answer (score 1):

You function will be something like that.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let controller1 = NextViewControoler()
    controller1.data = dataSource["products"]["data"][indexPath.row]
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller1, animated: true)
}
```

**Description**

1. `dataSource` will be that variable who store the `JSON` data.
2. `dataSource["products"]` will give you the key-value dictionary.
       `dataSource["products"]["data"]` will give you another key-value
       dictionary which contains the array of `data`.
3. `dataSource["products"]["data"][indexPath.row]` will give you the
       selected item dictionary.

Please note that you might need to do some casting to get your required data.

Comment: after write this code `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        
              let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
                let controller1 = DescriptionCollectionView(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        controller1.data = arrProduct["products"]["data"][indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller1, animated: true)
    }`              `Value of type 'DescriptionCollectionView' has no member 'data'`

Comment: What value you want to pass to DescriptionCollectionView?

Comment: It says that you have not declared any variable names data.

Comment: please verify what value will return this arrProduct["products"]["data"][indexPath.row] statement.

Comment: do you have chat own chat room

Comment: i have three controller Everything i did programmatically, i have success to perform pushViewController from CategoryCollectionViewController to ListTableViewController. but got the problem when i went to push from ListTableViewController to DescriptionCollectionViewController.

Comment: I didn't have a chat room but you can create and invite me in.

Comment: come to my chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154116/azmal-tech

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154118/discussion-between-azmal-tech-and-usman-javed).

Comment: @AzmalTech - what the issue u faced bro

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i am making mistake to write code in `didSelectRowAt indextPath` to push for collectionViewController

Comment: collectionViewController is your VC or else can you show the code related to collectionViewController

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i have three controller Everything i did programmatically, i have been success to perform pushViewController from CategoryCollectionViewController to ListTableViewController. but got the problem when i went to push from ListTableViewController to DescriptionCollectionViewController.

Comment: what the problem  u facing bro but got the problem when i went to push

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154130/discussion-between-azmal-tech-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: @UsmanJaved Brother! please come to this link to help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169737/swift-multiple-uibutton-in-a-indexpath-in-a-uicollectionviewcell-programmatical